# UK travel document holder going to Denmark?

Tags: visas, schengen, refugees, denmark, uk-residents

I am a UK refugee travel document holder, and I want to travel to Denmark. "Convention of 28th July 1951" is written on the back of my travel document.

I am going through Denmark in order to transit to go to Germany. Do I need to apply for a Schengen visa? What else do I need to travel in Denmark?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I travel to Denmark with UK refugee travel documents?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/can-i-travel-to-denmark-with-uk-refugee-travel-documents)

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica the answers there are largely pre-Brexit and out-of-date.

Comment: @mlc That means it’s time to add new answers and edit old ones. It doesn’t mean the question isn’t a duplicate.

Comment: @Sneftel There’s a discussion on dealing with old questions/information [here](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3464/how-to-deal-with-old-question-and-old-information). Perhaps some very old (5+years?) questions should be closed rather than updated, particularly where the answer has changed significantly? And/or flagged as out-of-date, as the Meta discussion mentions. Very old questions with multiple answers could be confusing/unclear. How, for example, should an ‘accepted answer’ be treated when it becomes incorrect over time? How would a new answer gain prominence over it?

Comment: @mlc Thanks, you're quite right. I've withdrawn my VTC.

Answer (score 2):

According to [IATA](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/page/travelinformation/5693494268/modify.htm) you need a visa.

> Visa required.
>
> The following should be taken into account even if holding a Visa:
> Visitors are required to hold proof of sufficient funds to cover their stay (at least DKK 350.- per day of intended stay).
>
> Warning:
> Visas for travel to the Faroe Isl. and/or Greenland are required to be endorsed "Valid for the Faroe Islands", "Valid for Greenland" or "Valid for the Faroe Islands and Greenland".

Comment: If OP is passing through Denmark in transit on the way to Germany, should they not be checking the visa requirements for Germany rather than Denmark?

Comment: @ThePhoton My answer is based on inputting Germany as the destination and Denmark as transit into the IATA site, however the OP can check for themselves using the link.